# How can I remove spaces around a SVG?

Tags: svg

I know there are a lots of posts related to this, I had checked all of them and I was not able to get a proper solution for my problem that's why I post this question.

I have a SVG like this:

[image]

As you can see that this SVG has no spaces around left and top, but it has some spaces around right and bottom. How can I remove the spaces which at bottom and right side of it?

SVG's source code: stackoverflow's body can have only up-to 30000 characters only but the SVG's source code has more characters than the limitation. Due to reason I had to upload the code at this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/chinkysight/5a71a4a72c18318997f4eb7aa9d67548?short_path=14c1ed3). I am really sorry for the inconvenience :(

Comment: You probably need to adjust the viewBox values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the borders of the SVG canvas I added to the header of the SVG file red border style

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1024 768" version="1.1" 
 style="border:1px solid red;">
```

Your image is shifted left and up so there are empty spaces on the right and bottom

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ze7crdqk/)

The image shift is performed by the command:

`<g id="girl" transform="translate(-35.000000, -89.000000)">`
Remove this command or set the coordinates to zero

`<g id="girl" transform="translate(0, 0)">`

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ze7crdqk/1/)

As a result, the empty spaces will disappear and the image will occupy the entire SVG canvas.

Comment: Thank you so much, you save my day :)

Comment: I have a question, is it possible to remove that rectangle and let svg be transparent ?

Comment: @ChinkySight Yes, it even needs to be done, remove the style from the file header, I added it for clarity

Comment: I wasn't taking about that red border you added to clarify me, I am taking about the black rectangular box. Is there any to remove it so that it can be like PNG border except content and of course transparent

Comment: @ChinkySight Do you want it like that? https://jsfiddle.net/ze7crdqk/2/

Comment: @ChinkySight To make the girl's leg transparent, write fill = "none" instead of fill = "#fff" https://jsfiddle.net/ze7crdqk/3/